# Error when Executing a python code

Tags: python

I am new to Python programming. I am writing the code below, and when I execute it the IDE returns an error message : TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Code below :

```
print("What is your name?")


name = input()

print("What is your age?")

age = input()

if name=='Jack':

  print ("Hello Jack")

elif age<12:

    print("You are not Jack")
```

The error

```
    elif age<12:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: It seems that you are comparing a string with an integer.

Comment: You need to cast your age input to an int.

Comment: So many duplicates of this, but where to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string.  You cannot directly compare a string to an integer.

Convert `age` to an integer by calling `int()`:

```
age = int(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

Tip:

```
print('something')
input()
# same as
input('something')
```

Then, `input` returns in python 3 a **string**. And you cannot compare a string with an int.

It's like if you were doing `'5' < 2`. You need to transform `'5'` into an int. And it's pretty easy: `int('5') == 5`

```
name = input("What is your name?")

age = input("What is your age?")

if name == 'Jack':
     print("Hello Jack")

elif int(age) < 12:

    print("You are not Jack")
```

Matt